# how to call another form within first in qt

Tags: mysql, forms, qt

I've qt 5.3.1 & mysql client in centos 6.6 (x86) in one VM and second VM contains server Mysql.
in qt i want to call second form ( "tabledispalaydialog.ui" ) from first form ("myappmanwindow.ui")

"tabledispalaydialog.ui" file contains one tableviewLoginForm ( tableview object from components of Qt creator design page)

the first form is this - login form(mainWindow):

[image]

second form to display query result :-
tableview in second form

[image]

now i want to call form "tabledispalaydialog.ui" in signal "click" of login button in form "myappmanwindow.ui".

And also i want to show "login table" from mysql server in second form, query 
 passed  as argument from first form.

finally how to `connect(this, SIGNAL(otherform(QString Query)),this, SLOT(callThisForm(QString Query)));`

### myappmainwindow.h :-

```c++
  #ifndef MYAPPMAINWINDOW_H
  #define MYAPPMAINWINDOW_H

  #include <QMainWindow>
  #include "tabledispalaydialog.h"
  #include <QSqlQueryModel>
  #include <QSqlDatabase>
  #include <QSqlDriver>
  #include <QMessageBox>
  #include <QSqlQuery>
  #include <QSqlRecord>
  #include <QMessageBox>

  namespace Ui {
  class MyappMainWindow;
  }

  class TableDispalayDialog;

  class MyappMainWindow : public QMainWindow
  {
      Q_OBJECT

  public:
      explicit MyappMainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
      ~MyappMainWindow();

  private:
      Ui::MyappMainWindow *ui;

      TableDispalayDialog *tableDisplayform;
      QSqlDatabase *db;

  signals:
      void otherform(QString Query);

  private slots:
      void on_pushButtonLogin_clicked();
  };

  #endif // MYAPPMAINWINDOW_H
```

### tabledispalaydoialog.h:-

```c++
   #ifndef TABLEDISPALAYDIALOG_H
   #define TABLEDISPALAYDIALOG_H

   #include <QDialog>
   #include <QSqlQueryModel>

   namespace Ui {
   class TableDispalayDialog;
   }

   class TableDispalayDialog : public QDialog
   {
       Q_OBJECT

   public:
       explicit TableDispalayDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
       ~TableDispalayDialog();



   private:
       Ui::TableDispalayDialog *ui;

       QSqlQueryModel *model;

   public slots:

       void callThisForm(QString Query);
   };       

   #endif        // TABLEDISPALAYDIALOG_H
```

### myappmainwindow.cpp :-

```c++
  #include "myappmainwindow.h"
  #include "ui_myappmainwindow.h"

  MyappMainWindow::MyappMainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
      QMainWindow(parent),
      ui(new Ui::MyappMainWindow)
        {
            ui->setupUi(this);

            TableDispalayDialog *tableDisplayform = new         ableDispalayDialog();
      //connect(this, SIGNAL(otherform(QString Query)),tableDisplayform, SLOT(callThisForm(QString Query)));
      //connect(this, SIGNAL(otherform(QString Query)),, SLOT(callThisForm(QString Query)));

       db = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL"));
       db->setDatabaseName("test");
       db->setHostName("oracle");
       db->setPort(3306);
       db->setUserName("rahul");
       db->setPassword("rahul");
  }

  MyappMainWindow::~MyappMainWindow()
  {
      db->close();
      delete ui;
  }

  void MyappMainWindow::on_pushButtonLogin_clicked()
  {
      QString susername = ui->lineEditUser->text();
      QString spassword = ui->lineEditPassword->text();
      QString strquery;

          strquery = "select * from tablelogin where user = \"" + susername.trimmed() +"\" " +" and password = \""+
                              spassword.trimmed()+ "\";";

      QMessageBox::information(this, "login button", strquery);
      }
```

### and at last table tabledispalaydialog.cpp :-

```c++
   #include "tabledispalaydialog.h"
   #include "ui_tabledispalaydialog.h"

   TableDispalayDialog::TableDispalayDialog(QWidget *parent) :
       QDialog(parent),
       ui(new Ui::TableDispalayDialog)
   {
       ui->setupUi(this);
   }

   TableDispalayDialog::~TableDispalayDialog()
   {
       delete ui;
   }

   void  TableDispalayDialog::callThisForm(QString Query)
   {
       this->model = new QSqlQueryModel();
       this->model->setQuery(Query);
       this->ui->tableViewLoginForm->setModel(model);
       this->show();
       this->setModal(true);
       this->exec();
   }
```

how can I call second form (TableDispalayDialog ) within first form(myappmanwindow) in button "login" click signal, and also having login table(from mysql) details in form TableDispalayDialog's tableview component.

Comment: please review this example first [login dialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#accepted)

Answer (score 0):

try using QSignalMapper http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html
to emit signals like clicked with a QString Parameter
or you can simply create a slot to call the form and pass the string as a parameter to the form constructor
or create a top level widget that handles all other widgets